# $\Vert Z\Vert_2^2\overset{\text{d}}{\underset{\text{}}{=}}\sum_{k=1}^d\lambda_kw_k^2,\,$ where $w_k\sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normal-distribution

> Let $\Sigma\in \mathbb R^{d,d}$ positive semi definit and $Z\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ a random vector in $\mathbb R^d$. 
>   I want to show that $\Vert Z\Vert_2^2\overset{\text{d}}{\underset{\text{}}{=}}\sum_{k=1}^d\lambda_kw_k^2,\,$ where $w_k\sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d. random variables and $\lambda_i \,,i=1,\dots d$ are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$.

My thoughts:

Since $\Sigma$ is postiv semi defint all its eigenvalues are non negative. By definition of $Z=(Z_1,\dots,Z_d)$ where each $Z_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$ $$\Vert Z\Vert_2^2= Z_1^2+\dots + Z_d^2=\sigma_1^2 \frac{Z_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\dots + \sigma_d^2 \frac{Z_d^2}{\sigma_d^2}\overset{\text{d}}{\underset{\text{}}{=}}\chi_1^2\sigma_1^2+\dots + \chi_1^2\sigma_d^2$$I do not see how to continue here, clearly each $w_i^2\sim \chi_1^2$, but now?

Comment: How comes the diagonalization of $\Sigma$ is not even mentioned in your approach?

Comment: @Did I do not see how the diagonalization of $\Sigma$ will help here!?

Comment: To see how this helps, you might wish to recall what is the most convenient property of the random variables $Z_k$ considered as a whole, which holds when $\Sigma$ is diagonal but not otherwise?

Comment: $\Sigma $ diagonal iff $Z_i$ pairwise independent

Comment: Excellent. Thus...

Comment: if $\Sigma$ was already in diagonal form I would be done since then $\lambda_i = \sigma_i^2$, but this is not given, so I still do not understand your hint

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is not diagonal, can you build a vector $W$ depending linearly on $Z$ and such that $W$ has diagonal covariance matrix? (This is odd, because everything I wrote so far is ultra standard...)

Comment: I do not see how...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix should get you started

Answer (score 2):

Let $W\sim N(0,I)$ and use eigendecomposition (see comment above) to write $\Sigma = Q\Lambda Q’$. Then $Z’Z \sim W’ \Sigma W \sim (Q’W)’ \Lambda (Q’W)\sim W’\Lambda W$, where the last equality in distribution follows from $Var(Q’W) = Q’Q=I$.